# Using class in Twig template with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, twig

I'm using Twig with CodeIgniter and by the past, I used to do something like that with PHP views:

```
<?php if($this->ion_auth->logged_in()): ?>
```

But now I'm using Twig, I just can't find a way to call the function logged_in() in the class ion_auth(). Any idea of how I could do that?

Answer (score 0):

I am working on this myself and will post an answer, but I'm interested in others who have tackled this. I believe it has something to do with registering the functions with Twig. I know it's possible in general with 'Twiggy' implementation of Twig for CodeIgniter. Issue for me is the version of Twig could be quite old as the Sparks project seems dated.